On Starting Trigger Pipeline Trigger keeps failing
I'm new to ADF, I ended up creating a pipeline with 2 data flow in the pipeline.
I tested the pipeline and everything is working up until I start the trigger!
After I start the trigger, I start receiving failure messages in the monitor Triggered section. (see image below)
The error message that I get under the status column is

Execution has been throttled as concurrency value is set and maximum
number of waiting runs have been queued. Please wait for current runs
to complete or cancel stuck runs.

Under the Parameters column when I click the link it shows:
Parameter Name is pipelineFileName and the value of the parameter is part-00004-1ec52bd3-a83a-41a6-9bd0-d63b719c2448-c000.csv
This file is nowhere to be found in blob storage, the blob storage is currently empty of any csv files.
At one point when I was designing this pipeline, I tested it and it created bunch of files with weird names on the blob storage. I ended up stopping the trigger then, could these files are still in the queue of the trigger?! If yes, what do I do? is there a way to clear them so I can start fresh?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.






The error message state that you set a concurrency value for the pipeline - meaning only x instances of this pipeline can run in parallel. If more than x instances were started, for example, if you put a lot of files in the folder that triggers the pipeline, then the rest of the pipelines runs will be stuck on status "waiting" until previous runs complete and they can start.
On the monitor tab, look for any pipeline runs that are either "running" or "waiting" and cancel them. Then, start the trigger again and put file(s) in the folder to test the trigger.

The concurrency is already set to 1. I have added the image in my initial question.
Back to the main questions

could these files are still in the queue of the trigger?!
If yes, what do I do?
is there a way to clear them so I can start fresh?


It appears that the queue retained the files that were deleted from the blob storage.
In order to clear the queue, I had to detach the trigger from the pipeline then publish the pipeline then reattach it back then publish.

